# How to create a windows docker image in aws codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

Is it possible to create a windows based docker image in code build? We could not find any docs on AWS regarding this. Any help on how to create a windows based docker image in CodeBuild will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As on may 25th 2018 AWS codebuild added support for windows based containers, the default enviroment supports .net core out of the box if you want to build your custom windows based enviroment then you need to first create your custom docker image on windows based host and then push it to AWS ECR container registry, then you can give reference to this image in your custom build enviroment in code build.

for more information click on this link

[code build for windows container](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/aws-codebuild-adds-support-for-windows-builds/)